# Not able to reach successRedirect using passport for facebook

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, passport-facebook

I am writing a "todolist" web application and use **passport-facebook** for third party authentication. Here is the code I use:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
   clientID: '566950043453498',
   clientSecret: '555022a61da40afc8ead59c6c26306ed',
   callbackURL: 'http://www.localhost:3000/auth/facebook/Todolistpage.html'
},
 function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("hello " + profile.displayName);

    done(null); 
 }
));

//Authentication
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/Todolistpage.html',
passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect:'/auth/facebook/Todolistpage.html',
                                  failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

A user clicks on the following:

```
<a href="/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>
```

I log in with facebook successfully but I am redirected to the path specified in the **failureRedirect** part of code. How come it does this and how do I make it go to the path specified in **successRedirect** if one logs in on facebook successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me'], failureRedirect: '/', successRedirect: 'back' }));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/facebook' }), users.authCallback);
```

in server site code :

```
exports.authCallback = function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
} // this will help you to redirect specific page.
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to also set callbackURL in FacebookStrategy to '/auth/facebook/callback' if you are changing the endpoint :)

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
   clientID: '566950043453498',
   clientSecret: '555022a61da40afc8ead59c6c26306ed',
   callbackURL: 'http://www.localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback'
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log("hello " + profile.displayName);
    done(null); 
 }
));

//Authentication
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/login?failedSocial=facebook'
  }), auth.authCallback);
```

and in auth service

```
exports.authCallback = function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
}
```